# Add ActionBar dynamically without using xml layout file in android

Tags: android

I want to add actionBar programmatically in android since I'm generating the page layout dynamically without using .xml layout (by reading json file )....I've tried it with defining other layout & then setting  its view using LayoutInflater ...Pls let me know how to define it since I'm new to android .

Comment: Can you post your code with what you've tried so far? Thank you.

Comment: try {  JSONObject root = new JSONObject(InputJSONFileString);
        JSONArray array = root.getJSONArray(JsonArrayName);
        len = array.length();  View mainDivider = new View(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lplp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
            lplp.setMargins(20, 50, 20, 10);
            mainDivider.setLayoutParams(lplp);
            mainDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            ll.addView(mainDivider);
}}

Comment: The above code is just an instance...I've actually written 600 lines of code for Dynamic form UI generation...but on stackoverflow it doesn't support long character format

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

```
getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();
```

Comment: Hey I figured it out by importing menu.xml in onCreateOption() using LayoutInflater & its event in onOptionItemSelected() method....thnxx though